# How do you prove that there does not exist a 2013 x 2013 matrix having the column space equal to the null space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am so bad with proofs... 
Can someone solve this through so I can use it as an example to solve other problems?

How do you prove that there does not exist a $2013 \times 2013$ matrix having the column space equal to the null space?

Comment: Is this from some ongoing constest? The $2013$ is awfully suspicious.

Comment: That was false last year. Mathematics can be seasonal.

Answer (score 2):

$$rank(A) + nullity(A) = dim(A)$$

So assume $x := rank(A) = nullity(A)$,

Then
$$x + x = 2013$$

So 
$$x = \dfrac{2013}{2}$$

But this is not an integer, so $A$ would have a non-integer rank, which is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{column space})+\operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{null space})=2013$.